# bash sub process won't be killed when main process been killed

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell

everyone.
I have wrote a bash script to monitor cpu, memory and network information. Everything is just fine with cpu and memory parts. But when it comes to network part, things become interesting.
I use "ifstat" to monitor network. "ifstat" is a block thread that will continuously print network IO on the screen. My bash script is like below:
    #!/bin/bash

```
#ignore other less important codes
......

ifstat > network.info &
while true
do
  ...
done
```

I use
    bash xx.sh 
to run it and use ctrl + c to kill it. And the odd thing appears, although this bash process has been killed but ifstat process is still running on the background. I use 
    ps -e | grep ifstat
to check it out. It's always there util I killed it manually.

In my opinion, ifstat process is a sub process of xx.sh, so I expect it be killed when I kill xx.sh. But obviously it is not !!!
Somebody can tell me why?
And how to kill it automatically when I kill xx.sh process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trap termination and propogate the kill.

```
#ignore other less important codes

ifstat > network.info &

IFSTAT_PID=$!
trap "kill $IFSTAT_PID $$" TERM INT HUP 0

while true
do
  ...
done
```

Comment: This solution is great! Thank you! But one more question is that why I killed shell process it won't kill ifstat process automatically as ifstat process is the sub process of the shell process(I think).